# Break statement always gets executed

Tags: java

This might be a stupid question but we're beginners and I didn't find an answer to my problem so here it is: We're developping a file system (small based) and we have this method that is supposed to move files from one Directory to another. (Deleting the file or directory from one and adding to another.)

We're using ArrayLists to store the Items (Item is then superclass of Directory and File).

Because of the fact that everything has to be sorted alphabetically, the method to move contains a while loop to verify where the item has to be placed (no preferences to Directories or Files) but for some reason the break statement I inserted is ALWAYS executed (or at least that's what I think is the reason.) Thanks!

Here's the code:

```
    if(item != null){
        boolean bool = false;
        int i = 0;
        loop: while(!bool && i <= items.size()-1) {
            if(i==0) {
                if(checkIfAlphabetic(item.getName(), items.get(0).getName())){ items.add(0,item);
                bool = true;
                }
                else{
                    break loop;
                }
            }
            else if(checkIfAlphabetic(items.get(i-1).getName(), item.getName()) && checkIfAlphabetic(item.getName(), items.get(i).getName() )) {
                items.add(i, item);
                bool = true;
            }
            else i++;
        }
        if(!bool){
            items.add(item);
        }
        setModificationTime();
    }
```

I already excuse myself if there are some things unclear.

PS. Also for some reason the Item I want to add always gets added twice.

As requested, the code for checkIfAlphabetic:

```
        private boolean checkIfAlphabetic(String search, String target){
    int[] searchInt = search.codePoints().toArray();
    int[] targetInt = target.codePoints().toArray();
    int i = 0;
    while(i<search.length() && i<target.length()){
        if(searchInt[i] > targetInt[i]){
            return false;
        }
        else if(searchInt[i] < targetInt[i]) return true;
        else i++;
    }

    if(search.length() < target.length()){
        return true;
    }
    else return false;

}
```

Comment: can you provide code for `checkIfAlphabetic` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `while` loop is faulty. It will always stop after the first iteration, no matter what.

This is what happens in order of statements. This is pseudo-code, not Java. Don't copy/paste, it won't work.

```
boolean bool = false;
int i = 0;
// entering the while loop:
if (!bool && i <= items.size() - 1) // returns true. We go in the while loop.
if (i == 0) // returns true, we go in that block.
if (check... ) // if this returns true, this happens:
    bool = true;
else // if the previous statement returns false, this happens:
    break;
```

So here, if the check... returns false, we're gonna get out of the loop. Let's continue in the other case:

```
// nothing else happens inside the loop, so go back to the loop condition.
if (!bool && i <= items.size() - 1) // Hey, wait a minute, bool is true. So "not" true is false. The condition is therefore not met, let's leave the loop.
```

So this is what happens, after a single execution, no matter what, your code exits the loop. In your scenario, `bool = true` is the near absolute equivalent to a `break`.

This is what you need to fix.

If I had to write your code, this is how I'd do it:

```
List<Item> items = ... ;
java.util.Collections.sort(items, new ItemNameComparator());

 private static class ItemNameComparator implements Comparator<Item> {
  @Override
  public int compare(Item a, Item b) {
    return a.getName().compareTo(b.getName());
  }
}
```

If you use Java 8:

```
List<Item> items = ...;
items.sort((a, b) -> a.getName().compareTo(b.getName()));
```

All the tools exist in the Java libraries, use them instead of reimplementing them again and again.

Comment: yes I know they exist, I'm sorry I forgot to mention. This is an assignment for our programming classes and we were explicitly told not to use the compareTo() function... That's why we had to reimplement it. I do however see what you mean with the while loop... So that'll have to change for sure. I'll try to adjust it correctly now. Thanks! :)